# Do I really have to use DateSerial to set a date parameter in a QueryDef in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a better way to set date parameters within a `VIEW` in MS Access?  I find myself using a `DateSerial` and setting integers within that.  There has to be a better way, using a `cDate` or something to do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM pay_schedule_with_run_date
WHERE payroll_number IN (SELECT max(payroll_number) FROM pay_schedule_with_run_date x WHERE x.ssTravelGenUpdateRunDate <= DateSerial(yr, mth, dy) AND x.pay_date >= DateSerial(yr, mth, dy));
```

**MS-Access `VIEW` named `getSSTravelGenUpdate_payperiod_by_runDate`**

```
Set getSSTravelGenUpdate_payperiod_by_runDate = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("getSSTravelGenUpdate_payperiod_by_runDate")

todaysDate = Now()

With getSSTravelGenUpdate_payperiod_by_runDate
        .Parameters("yr").Value = 2016 ' Year(todaysDate)
        .Parameters("mth").Value = 2   ' Month(todaysDate)
        .Parameters("dy").Value = 29   ' Day(todaysDate)
End With

Set rsWhichPayPeriod = getSSTravelGenUpdate_payperiod_by_runDate.OpenRecordset
```

**Code to set a date parameter within the `getSSTravelGenUpdate_payperiod_by_runDate` `VIEW`.**

Comment: There aren't any views in MS ACCESS, however, if you are using date column you can compare them like Gustav suggested. if you are using dateTime column just don't forget 01/03/2016 != 01/03/2016 06:00:00

Comment: @krishKM If that's true, what's the difference between a query and a view?

Comment: Google it. If you have any problem understanding it, raise another question with your concern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108664/difference-between-views-and-select-queries

Comment: I'm talking about an MS-Access query not a select query I guess....it seems to me that `VIEW`s in MS-Access are called queries, even though they're more like `VIEW`s, since you can name them and pull other VIEWs or SELECT queries from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set one parameter in the query:

```
Parameters RunDate DateTime;
SELECT *
FROM pay_schedule_with_run_date
WHERE payroll_number IN (SELECT max(payroll_number) FROM pay_schedule_with_run_date x WHERE x.ssTravelGenUpdateRunDate <= RunDate AND x.pay_date >= RunDate);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the right language?  It looks like C#. (at the top)  Sorry maybe I confused it...it's VBA in Access 2003/2010

Comment: @leeand00 This query is legitimate and can be saved as a stored query in MS Access (not just VBA).

Comment: It is SQL in Access. That's how parameters are specified by name and data type. Can be done via the GUI too.