# oracle select statement reuse?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, select

This is an extract sql that gets days

```
AND S.Date          IN

  (
    SELECT Date
    FROM
      (
      SELECT Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC )-1 Day
      FROM CALENDAR_DIM
      WHERE TYPE               = 'ABC'
      )
    WHERE BUS_DAY BETWEEN 0 AND 2
  )
```

I want to run this code twice in two parts of my sql. How can i do that without pasting the same code. Also .. how could i rewrite the above code?. I am having some issues with performance.

Comment: think you have a typo : shouldn't it be `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC )-1 BUS_DAY`, or I don't know where your BUS_DAY comes from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1** : use a WITH statement

```
WITH dateQuery  AS (
    SELECT Date
    FROM
      (
      SELECT Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC )-1 BUS_DAY
      FROM CALENDAR_DIM
      WHERE TYPE = 'ABC'
      )
    WHERE BUS_DAY BETWEEN 0 AND 2)



SELECT xxx
FROM yyy
WHERE zzz
AND s.Date IN (SELECT Date FROM dateQuery)
```

The only part to repeat will then be

```
SELECT Date FROM dateQuery
```

**Solution 2** : create a View

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_DATE_QUERY AS
(   SELECT Date
    FROM
      (
      SELECT Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC )-1 BUS_DAY
      FROM CALENDAR_DIM
      WHERE TYPE = 'ABC'
      )
    WHERE BUS_DAY BETWEEN 0 AND 2)
```

and use it the same way

```
AND s.Date IN (Select Date FROM V_DATE_QUERY);
```

Comment: @user648244 because it's a "materialized" subquery (Oracle transforms it as an inline view or as a temporary table.), and not just a subquery. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm

Answer (score 1):

You would make this a [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256700/what-is-a-view-in-oracle) in your database like so:

```
CREATE VIEW view_date
AS
SELECT Date,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC )-1 Day
FROM CALENDAR_DIM
WHERE TYPE               = 'ABC'
```

Now you can use:

```
AND S.Date          IN

  (
    SELECT Date
    FROM view_date
    WHERE BUS_DAY BETWEEN 0 AND 2
  )
```