# Creating a database table in Oracle from multiple sources

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I am getting data from two different table sources.  What is the best way to combine them into one?

For example:

**table one** has the following columns:

```
date | time | exchange
```

**table two** has the following columns:

```
date | time | price | position
```

**I want to combine them so I can create a table that has:**

```
date | time | exchange | position | price
```

Sometimes position and exchange columns are empty.  What is the best way to create this new table?

Comment: what's the problem about having these fields empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend further reading into SQL JOINs. [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Then read up on how Views represent data from multiple tables: [What is a View in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256700/what-is-a-view-in-oracle)

Then read up on how SQL UNION combines results from multiple tables: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Union

Read up on Creating a table from a select: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php

Understand materialized Views: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm

This just scratches the surface.  All of these will solve your requirement with various benefits and draw backs.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest using a join table as well, althought its not clear how your tables are truly related. You should understand [Normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)